# Recursive calls and variable assignment errors [Python]

Tags: python, variables, recursion, variable-assignment

I was just playing around testing if strings were immutable because I was a bit tired :D and made this

```
def x(string = "a", y = 0):
    if y == 5:
        return
    else:
        string += "x"
        print(string)
        x(string, y = y + 1)
        print(string)
x()
```

and I am simply wondering why this works but

```
def x(string = "a", y = 0):
    if y == 5:
        return
    else:
        string += "x"
        print(string)
        x(string, y += 1)
        print(string)
x()
```

Does not work (The difference in the y variable assignment in the recursive call). Why is it a syntax error, theyre simply doing the same thing?

Comment: syntax error means python cannot accept this input in its grammar.

Comment: That's a lot of code to produce a syntax error. Try to produce the same error with as little code as possible, forget about recursion and strings.

Comment: Try printing `y` after the recursive call to `x()` and you will find it hasn't changed. You are using the keyword arg `y` not assignment to `y` in your `x()` function call.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version, you tell the function that your parameter `y` takes the value of your variable `y`, +1. If your parameter was called `z`, you'd have `x(string, z=y+1)`.

As you see, `y+=1` doesn't work, there you're attempting to modify your variable, not to give the function a named parameter. But `+=` doesn't return anything, so the syntax is indeed incorrect.

Comment: but y = y + 1 doesn't return anything either

Comment: y in this case is a parameter name, like my_param=y+1, it's not an assignment but passing a named parameter to a function ..